Not able to change the background color of header using Chakra-UI component
I am using Chakra-UI's styling conventions to try to style the background color of the header. The styles for the header is located in Header.js:
export default {
    baseStyle: {
        container: {
            minWidth: 'xs',
            width: 'full',
            boxShadow: 'base',
            backgroundColor: 'blue'
        },
        content: {
            maxWidth: 'container.xxxl',
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
            paddingLeft: [4, 4, 6, 8],
            paddingRight: [4, 4, 6, 8],
            paddingTop: [1, 1, 2, 4],
            paddingBottom: [3, 3, 2, 4]
        },
    },
    parts: ['container', 'content', 'searchContainer', 'bodyContainer', 'logo', 'icons', 'signout']
}

As you can see, I tried changing the background color to blue, but it doesn't do anything. See below for the code in the Header file for the markup:
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {useIntl} from 'react-intl'
import {
    useMultiStyleConfig,
    Box,
    Flex,
    IconButton,
    Badge,
    Button,
    Popover,
    PopoverHeader,
    PopoverTrigger,
    PopoverContent,
    PopoverBody,
    PopoverFooter,
    PopoverArrow,
    Stack,
    Text,
    Divider,
    useDisclosure,
    useMediaQuery
} from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/components/shared/ui'
import {AuthHelpers, useAuthHelper, useCustomerType} from '@salesforce/commerce-sdk-react'

import {useCurrentBasket} from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/hooks/use-current-basket'

import Link from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/components/link'
import withRegistration from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/components/with-registration'
import {
    AccountIcon,
    BrandLogo,
    BasketIcon,
    HamburgerIcon,
    ChevronDownIcon,
    HeartIcon,
    SignoutIcon,
    SearchIcon
} from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/components/icons'

import {navLinks, messages} from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/pages/account/constant'
import useNavigation from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/hooks/use-navigation'
import LoadingSpinner from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/components/loading-spinner'
import {isHydrated, noop} from '@salesforce/retail-react-app/app/utils/utils'

const IconButtonWithRegistration = withRegistration(IconButton)

const Header = ({
    children,
    onMenuClick = noop,
    onSearchClick = noop,
    onMyAccountClick = noop,
    onLogoClick = noop,
    onMyCartClick = noop,
    onMiniCartClick = noop,
    onWishlistClick = noop,
    ...props
}) => {
    const intl = useIntl()
    const {
        derivedData: {totalItems},
        data: basket
    } = useCurrentBasket()
    const {isRegistered} = useCustomerType()
    const logout = useAuthHelper(AuthHelpers.Logout)
    const navigate = useNavigation()
    const {
        getButtonProps: getAccountMenuButtonProps,
        getDisclosureProps: getAccountMenuDisclosureProps,
        isOpen: isAccountMenuOpen,
        onClose: onAccountMenuClose,
        onOpen: onAccountMenuOpen
    } = useDisclosure()
    const [isDesktop] = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 992px)')

    const [showLoading, setShowLoading] = useState(false)
    // tracking if users enter the popover Content,
    // so we can decide whether to close the menu when users leave account icons
    const hasEnterPopoverContent = useRef()

    const styles = useMultiStyleConfig('Header')

    const onSignoutClick = async () => {
        setShowLoading(true)
        await logout.mutateAsync()
        navigate('/login')
        setShowLoading(false)
    }

    const handleIconsMouseLeave = () => {
        // don't close the menu if users enter the popover content
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (!hasEnterPopoverContent.current) onAccountMenuClose()
        }, 100)
    }

    return (
        <Box {...styles.container} {...props}>
            <Box {...styles.content}>
                
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}

Header.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    onMenuClick: PropTypes.func,
    onLogoClick: PropTypes.func,
    onSearchClick: PropTypes.func,
    onMyAccountClick: PropTypes.func,
    onWishlistClick: PropTypes.func,
    onMyCartClick: PropTypes.func,
    onMiniCartClick: PropTypes.func,
    searchInputRef: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.func,
        PropTypes.shape({current: PropTypes.elementType})
    ])
}

export default Header
I tried things like inline styles, which work, but that isn't ideal when I have an external styles file for this component.
